# How to draw scroll-based moving circles like this website ? http://bearideas.fr/who-we-are/

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll

I want to draw scroll-based moving circles like this site(http://bearideas.fr/who-we-are/). First time i used canvas and draw random circles but its hard to control object when scroll moved.Pls help me guys. What you suggest me? Another words which javascript library can make this easy. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You could use SVG to draw circles.

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}




    
 var circles = document.querySelectorAll("circle");
 
 for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
     var circle = circles[i];
     circle.setAttribute("cx", getRandomInt(0,300));
     circle.setAttribute("cy", getRandomInt(0,300));
     circle.setAttribute("r", getRandomInt(30,60));
     $(circle)
   .velocity({ x: ("+=" + (200 + i * 10)), y: "25%" })
    .velocity({ fillGreen: 255, strokeWidth: 2 })
   .velocity({ height: 50, width: 50 })
    .velocity({ rotateZ: 90, scaleX: 0.5 })
    .velocity("reverse", { delay: getRandomInt(50,2000) })
    .velocity({ x: ("+=" + (200 + i * 10)), y: "25%" })
    .velocity({ fillGreen: 255, strokeWidth: 2 })
   .velocity({ height: 50, width: 50 })
    .velocity({ rotateZ: 90, scaleX: 0.5 })
    .velocity("reverse", { delay: getRandomInt(50,2000) })
    .velocity({ x: ("+=" + (200 + i * 10)), y: "25%" })
    .velocity({ fillGreen: 255, strokeWidth: 2 })
   .velocity({ height: 50, width: 50 })
    .velocity({ rotateZ: 90, scaleX: 0.5 })
    .velocity("reverse", { delay: getRandomInt(50,2000) })
    .velocity({ x: ("+=" + (200 + i * 10)), y: "25%" })
    .velocity({ fillGreen: 255, strokeWidth: 2 })
   .velocity({ height: 50, width: 50 })
    .velocity({ rotateZ: 90, scaleX: 0.5 })
    .velocity("reverse", { delay: getRandomInt(50,2000) })
    .velocity({ x: ("+=" + (200 + i * 10)), y: "25%" })
    .velocity({ fillGreen: 255, strokeWidth: 2 })
   .velocity({ height: 50, width: 50 })
    .velocity({ rotateZ: 90, scaleX: 0.5 })
    .velocity("reverse", { delay: getRandomInt(50,2000) });
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.0/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.0/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
<svg height="400" width="500">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  
</svg>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_circle.asp

Comment: approximately one page have 50 circles. If using svg , after don't have any problem ?

Comment: No, you could put hundreds on a page with little worry about performance.

Comment: @Alemcredits - I added a ton of circles and more animations.  Take a look.  :)  Did it work for you?

Comment: yeah. bro its work for me. But i have more another 1 question. I draw my circles and put it in my wordpress page but my wordpress page's texts don't appear i use z-index but its did'nt work for me . help bro ...

Comment: Can you do a separate question and link it here?  That way I can see examples, etc.  Also, can you accept this answer for this question? :)